# Chart.js: Get Hidden Datasets

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a multiseries line chart using Chart.js and I've been trying to figure out how to get hidden datasets from a Chart.js object. I want to display the filtered data in a table besides the Chart.

I tried adding a hidden variable for each dataset but I still am having trouble retrieving which datasets are hidden.

Answer (score 7):

how do you hide your datasets?
I just checked Chart.js document, and found that they have hidden option.
So, why don't you see at the hidden option?

```
// test chart.
var data =  {
    labels: ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "line-1",
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            data: [20, 26, 12, 43, 33, 21, 29],
            // hidden
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            label: "line-2",
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
            data: [10, 3, 24, 43, 23, 11, 51],
        },
        {
            label: "line-3",
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
            data: [16, 31, 22, 53, 24, 27, 69],
        }
    ]
};

// For hidden Label. (I don't know why datasets hasn't this option.)
var options = {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            filter: function(item, chart) {
                return !item.hidden;
            }
        }
    }
};

// Create the chart.
var myLineChart = new Chart($("#chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});

// Get the hidden datasets based on the hidden column.
var hiddenDatasets = $.grep(myLineChart.data.datasets, function(line) {
    return line.hidden;
});

// See console.
console.log(hiddenDatasets);
```

[Here's jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/139nL76p/)

**UPDATED**
I found that there is a useful method available.

```
var hiddenDatasets = [];
for(var i=0; i<myLineChart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
    // It seems some value updated in metadata, but there is a method available.
    // var metaDatasets = myLineChart.getDatasetMeta(i);
    if (!myLineChart.isDatasetVisible(i)) {
        // or myLineChart.getDatasetMeta(i);
        hiddenDatasets.push(myLineChart.data.datasets[i]);
    }
 }
 // See console.
 console.log(hiddenDatasets);
```

[jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/j5rL7am8/)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it will only return the default hidden datasets. It doesn't return any information about datasets that are disabled by the user by clicking on the legend.

Comment: I didn't get it that information from your question, but I think I could solve. (I updated my answer)

Comment: Whoops, did you try after seeing my answer?, in that case, I'm sorry I didn't check enough my code.

Comment: That method is exactly what I needed. In my scenario, I'm storing the hidden state in an object so I can restore that same state after refreshing the data. When I queried `myChart.data.datasets[i].hidden`, they were always false, even when the some were clearly hidden. `myChart.isDatasetVisible` correctly showed which ones were visible. This could be a bug that has since been fixed. I'm on version 2.8.0, which is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread googling, so in case there still isn’t a better way to do this than checking datasets one by one, here is a filter() version to copypaste:

```
myChart.data.datasets.filter((ds, i) => !myChart.isDatasetVisible(i) ? ds : undefined);
```

Or the reverse to get only the visible ones:

```
myChart.data.datasets.filter((ds, i) => myChart.isDatasetVisible(i) ? ds : undefined);
```